# Calling C function/subroutine in Fortran code

Tags: c, compilation, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am attempting to compile and link a Fortran code calling c subroutine:

Fortran code:

```
program adder
integer a,b
a=1
b=2
call addnums(a,b)
stop    
end program
```

C code:

```
void addnums( int* a, int* b ) 
{
    int c = (*a) + (*b);  /* convert pointers to values, then add them */
    printf("sum of %i and %i is %i\n", (*a), (*b), c );
}
```

I used the following commands to compile and link in windows environment.

```
ifort -c adder.f
cl -c addnums.c
ifort -o add adder.obj addnums.obj
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
-out:add.exe 
-subsystem:console 
adder.obj 
addnums.obj 
adder.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ADDNUMS referenced in function MAIN__
add.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Please help me resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try matching that function name (ie, all caps)?

Answer (score 20):

You need to provide an interface body for the C function inside the specification part of the Fortran main program that tells the Fortran compiler that the name `addnums` is a C function.  Something like:

```
INTERFACE
  SUBROUTINE addnums(a, b) BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(C_INT) :: a, b
  END SUBROUTINE addnums
END INTERFACE
```

(With those compilers on that platform without special options the default kind of integer is the same as C_INT - but being explicit about the integer KIND helps protect you if compiler/platform or compile options change.)

Comment: Thanks. Your suggested helped.

Answer (score 3):

Here's two things I can see right off the bat (I work mainly with FORTRAN77 so this may not be the newest or best way to do this):

1. Since your C function is, well, a function (and not a subroutine), you'll need to declare 'addnums' as EXTERNAL. Add this to your code in your declarations section.

   ```
   EXTERNAL addnums
   ```
2. Add an underscore to the name of the function in your C code. FORTRAN does this automatically to its own functions, but not to functions in other languages. So, the function's signature would be

   ```
   void addnums_( int* a, int* b )
   ```

[This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130317102755/http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/fortran/prog_guide/11_cfort.doc.html) has a pretty good rundown on mixing C and FORTRAN. Hope this helped!

Comment: The modern way of connecting Fortran and C is to use the Fortran ISO_C_Binding.  As part of the Fortran language, it is compiler and platform independent.  It avoids needing to know about compiler internals.  The linked page is obsolete.

Comment: If you are unable to use ISO_C binding, declare the C routine as __stdcall otherwise it defaults to __cdecl.  It will call your routine and crash on exit.

Comment: The link to "This page" is broken.

Comment: Another source for that page is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.8/817-5066/11_cfort.html Oracle will probably (inadvertently) break the link as soon as I post it so the Google-fu to find it later is to search for Sun/Oracle documentation for their Fortran compiler